# Double Integral : $\int^{1}_{0}\int^{1}_{\sqrt{y}}e^{x^3}dxdy$ without $\Gamma$ function.

Tags: integration, analysis, multivariable-calculus

I am having trouble finding a way to solve this: $$\int^{1}_{0}\int^{1}_{\sqrt{y}}e^{x^3}dxdy$$

The solution is $\frac1 3[e-1]$.

I reduced the integral to $\int^{1}_{0}[e^{x^3}-x^2e^{x^3}]dx$ but I can't seem to solve it further. I tried substituition and integration by parts and *I don't think Trig substitution will work, will it?*

Also because this is a solution from a multivariate book(Marsden,Tromba Vector Calculus) ***it should be solved without the use of the $\Gamma$ function.***

Thanks in advance.

Comment: $$\int_0^1x^2e^{x^3}\ dx=\frac13\int_0^1e^u\ du$$

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt Yes but that leaves the integral of $e^{x^3}$ which is apparently non elementary so I would guess that I can't separate them using additivity??

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just switch order by drawing the region out,

$$\int_{0}^{1} \int_{\sqrt{y}}^{1} e^{x^3}dx dy= \int_{0}^{1} \int_{0}^{x^2} e^{x^3}dy dx$$

Comment: When it's so trivial you die when you see the answer.

Comment: I see my mistake I had $x^2$ in the lower boundary of the inner interval. Thanks

Comment: when you see double integrals, try swappin' 'em.